# Matching null in should query in Elasticsearch 2.3.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field `gender` which can have three values:

- MALE
- FEMALE
- null

The mapping of `gender` is:

```
"gender": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

To match `null` I am following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query).

I used this query to get the documents with `gender` as `null`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "gender"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to build a `should` query so that the search results could return any documents having the `gender` field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "gender": {
                  "query": "MALE",
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "gender": {
                  "query": "FEMALE",
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "gender"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query above gives me 0 hits. How should I construct the right query for this?

Comment: You get 0 results because you use `must` with both `MALE` and `FEMALE` values. It should be `should` instead of `must`. And I don't understand what you do with `must_not` and `exists`.

Comment: How do I match the documents that have `gender` as `null`? I was following  [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query)

Comment: What is the mapping for the `gender` field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have added more details to the question

Comment: I updated my answer with a more advanced use case ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": {
              "query": "MALE",
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": {
              "query": "FEMALE",
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "gender"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

**or** if I didn't understand the question well and in fact you want to differentiate between `gender` **completely missing from a document** or the **field being there, but having `null`**, you need something else, that requires changing the mapping slightly:

```
    "gender": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "null_value": "_null_"
    }
```

And in this case the query is:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": {
              "query": "MALE"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "gender": {
              "query": "FEMALE"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "_null_"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

In this case, if you index:

```
{"index":{}}
{"gender":"MALE"}
{"index":{}}
{"gender":"FEMALE"}
{"index":{}}
{"gender":null}
{"index":{}}
{"gender2":"MALE"}
{"index":{}}
{"gender":"whatever"}
```

it will give you back:

```
     {
        "_score": 0.2826735,
        "_source": {
           "gender": "MALE"
        }
     },
     {
        "_score": 0.2826735,
        "_source": {
           "gender": null
        }
     },
     {
        "_score": 0.021688733,
        "_source": {
           "gender": "FEMALE"
        }
     }
```